# Does physics allow for targeting spacetime's coordinates of a second entrance of the wormhole?

Tags: spacetime, geometry, topology, wormholes

Is it possible to create a wormhole whose second entrance, with a certain degree of probability, will land at a given point of time and space (for example, a wormhole whose second entrance has the quantum probability that it will land in ancient Egypt, several thousand years ago)? I think skillful controlling of spacetime's topology and geometry should provide this mechanism.

Comment: You are putting the cart before the horse, so to speak. The wormhole conjecture is just that, a guess at what **could** beyond the event horizon. Nobody is currently able to answer your question, I am sorry to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wormhole is a solution of Einstein's field equations that connects two different spacetimes. Both heads of the wormhole might be in this universe, or they might connect two different universes. What you are describing is including quantum effects in the wormhole so that there will be some uncertainty in the location of one or both of the heads. To describe such a system seems to be exceedingly difficult, because if you are to include quantum effects such as you describe the wormhole would have to be microscopic. In such a limit, we would need to have an understanding of quantum gravity, which we don't have yet.

However, I can take a wormhole and distort the spacetime geometry around the heads so that there is a finite time difference $\Delta t$ between the two entrances. That is, if I could somehow exploit time dilation on one head, I could hypothetically have the wormhole form a closed timelike curve between the two regions. Unfortunately, it is well known that a transversable wormhole is impossible to construct, so if you jumped into the head, instead of finding yourself in ancient Egypt, you might meet your journey's end when you face the singularity in the wormhole's neck.

For more on wormholes and closed timelike curves, [look at this article by Thorne](https://www.its.caltech.edu/~kip/scripts/ClosedTimelikeCurves-II121.pdf). Also [look at this article by Thorne and Misner](http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/refael/league/thorne-morris.pdf) for a good technical introduction to the science of wormholes in general.